# Button needs to redirect to the same page at different URL

Tags: redirect, button

I have two domains:

**domain.com** and **domain.it**

Need to add a script/code to the language button so it redirects from all of the pages with English language to the same pages at Italian domain just replacing domain extension such as:

**domain.com/text.html** to **domain.it/text.html**

or

**domain.com/text1.html** to **domain.it/text1.html**

or

**domain.com/text2.html** to **domain.it/text2.html**

and etc.

How to go about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: Not really - this is about something else entirely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button onclick="redirect()">Italian Version</button>

<script>
function redirect()
{
  var currentUrl = window.location.href;
  var newUrl = currentUrl.replace(".com", ".it");
  window.location.replace(newUrl);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome Michael! Thanks!

Comment: And if I have to work with next code, how would you go about it?: 


<div mbr-buttons mbr-theme-style="display-4" class="mbr-section-btn" mbr-if="showButtons" data-toolbar="-mbrBtnMove"><a class="btn btn-md btn-secondary" href="index.html#toggle2-f9"><span class="socicon socicon-overwatch mbr-iconfont mbr-iconfont-btn"></span>ENTER</a></div>